# On click, remove div

Tags: angularjs

I am repeating divs with Angularjs as following:

```
        <div class="large-12 eachRow greyRow" ng-repeat="role in bindRoles">
            <div class="large-10 columns">
                {{role}}
            </div>
            <div class="large-2 columns">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle minusIconStyle"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
```

On clicking, the icon with class `minusIconStyle`. I need to remove the particular row alone. How can I achieve that with angularjs?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: When you click on `i` do you want to remove only the first child `div` or both children ?

Comment: Then entire div: 'greyRow'.

Comment: By remove, you mean to hide the row ??

Comment: Yea. But i dont want to show the div again

Answer (score 0):

Put a .hide attribute on each of your roles, initialised to false. Then add an ng-click="role.hide = true" to the element you want to be clickable. Finally, add ng-hide="role.hide" to the element you want to hide on clicking

Answer (score 0):

I got it working,

```
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle minusIconStyle" ng-click="removeRole(role)"></i>

    $scope.removeRole = function(role) {
      return $scope.bindRoles = $scope.bindRoles.filter(function(word) {
        return word !== role;
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="large-12 eachRow greyRow" ng-repeat="role in bindRoles">
                <div class="large-10 columns">
                    {{role}}
                </div>
                <div class="large-2 columns">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle minusIconStyle"
                        ng-click="$parent.bindRoles.splice($index,1);"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is your solution. After removing current element from the list ng repeat will run again and render the list without removed element.